# Select some element of a Cell by index - faster than for structure

Tags: matlab, cell

some small questions!

1. How can I create a null N-by-N cell in matlab?
2. I have a N-by-3 matrix

`rv=...        %# [N-by-3]`

`r=sqrt(sum(rv,2).^2);`
`if r < b`

`statement1`

`end`

Statement is save the index of r in a vector (like C).
Something like this: C=[1 3 4 7 9 ,…]
By use of this vector I want to select some element of a N-by-N matrix 
   Each element of a 2D matrix has 2 indexes: (i, j). If both of them be in the vector of indexes(C) then choose it and save it’s index in a cell
Something like this: D={[2x1] [2x1] …  }
Thanks a lot for any guide.
Whishes

=================================================================================

For the second one :

```
p=1
for i=1:N
    if r(i)<R
        L(p)=i;
        p=p+1;
    end
end


L=[.....];

for i=1:length(L)
    for j=1:length(L)
        D{i,j}=C{L(i),L(j)};
    end
end
```

but problem is that it has a for structure and is very slow. I'am looking for something faster. perhaps with  `combnk`

Comment: I want just select that elements that are in my list. if you have a better suggestion than D(cell) i listen eagerly.

Comment: For the first I think it is `A=cell(N);`

Comment: What do you mean by *index* of r?

Comment: @Phonon: I mean save the (i) for the (r)s that are true in if  in **L**, C is a N-by-N cell. I want to select some elemets of it in **D** by use of **L**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your question. But here I go.

I'd first convert indices of L from subscripts to indices with [sub2ind](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html). You can then use the resulting indices to generate a vectorize version of D, and use reshape to give it the final N-D version you want. Something like:

```
LInd = sub2Ind(size(C), L, L)
Dvect = C(LInd);
D = reshape(D, Shape_I_Want);
```

Hope this helps